# My entire website is not being displayed on github

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm not sure as to why my entire website is not displaying, i've tried everything that was recommended but still nothing works. My banner image and text is not showing up when I published the website on github.

What my website should look like:

file:///Users/tamannahoque/Documents/Skincare/index.html#products

(if that works)

The code:

https://github.com/TamannaHoque/the-ordinary.github.io

The website when published on github:

https://tamannahoque.github.io/the-ordinary.github.io/

Comment: When asking for help troubleshooting an issue with a website, please don't simply paste a link to the website into the question. Instead, include a [mre] of the issue within the question itself. Posts containing only a link to another website and no code in the question are likely to be closed for not having enough details.  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) for why this is required.

Comment: The reason your website is not working is because it needs to be `(your github username).github.io`. Unless you get github pages, you have to use your username as the  domain name. Also the file you linked is obviously not accessible to us.

Comment: The image path in the repository (`image`) does not match the one used in the HTML files (`Images`).

Answer (score 1):

The basic website is being displayed on GitHub; but, your images and other items the website refers to contain links that don't refer to the "GitHub published" locations, so all you are getting is the HTML.